# Remove 'title' from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame, which I split according to the variable 'redo':

```
y_by_redo_i <- split(y, y$redo) #so I have:
y_by_redo_i
$`1012`
employed redo
42       1012 
53       1012 
62       1012  etc.
$`1013`
employed redo
45       1013 
71       1013 
98       1013  etc.
```

I can call for example the 'first smaller' dataframe using:

```
y_by_redo_i[1] #or y_by_redo_i$'1012'
```

The difference is that in the first case it gives `$'1012'` as a title, as well. How can I remove this title, in order to obtain the same identical result with both commands? I want to use latter `y_by_redo_i[i]` in a 'for cycle'. Thank you guys!

Comment: `names(y_by_redo_i) <- NULL`, but it's very doubtful you need to split in the first place. Use grouping instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: I tried your command but I have the same problem; for example I can't ask nrow(y_by_redo_i[1])   NULL

Comment: `split` returns a list of data.frames, not a single data.frame. Subsetting a list with single brackets returns a list, too, and so asking for the number of rows of a list doesn't make sense. If you want to extract something from a list, use double brackets. There are lots of ways of grouping in R, but maybe start with `aggregate` or `dplyr::group_by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use double brackets, here's an example:

```
> dat<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:3,3,3))
> dat
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
> dat2<-split(dat,dat$V1)
> dat2[1]
$`1`
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1

> dat2[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1
```

Comment: It was so simple :) thanx! I think it will work in the 'for cycle', as well!